# Getting a 'nativeElement' of undefined when hidding and showing text input in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a text input which is a flex container with a button in it. If the box is visible the user can click on arrow to collapse / hide the box if its hidden a click will show the box. On init I also attach
a `@ViewChild` to be able to access the input.

My problem is that this works fine when I initial have `showTextInput=true` and the input is shown. When i click later on hide it the box is correctly removed and another click will show it again. But it seems after I hide the box and show it again it no longer seems to have the listener attached. I tried calling the `initAutoComplete()` when I set the `showTextInput=true` but then it complains

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

so my question how can i fix it or is there another way to archive this ?

```
@ViewChild('search', {static: false}) public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
```

That part works all fine.

```html
    <div id="pac-container">
    <div class="flexContainer" *ngIf="showTextInput">
    <input #search id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    <button (click)="hideInput()"><img src="arrow.png" alt="Hide Input"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer" *ngIf="!showTextInput">
    <button (click)="showInput()"><img src="arrow.png" alt="Show Input"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Then after `ngAfterViewInit()` I call this function `initAutoComplete()` which will monitor the Input and display the google data.

```typescript
    initAutoComplete() {
    this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // get the place result
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          // verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          // set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
          console.log(this.lat + ' - ' + this.lng)
        });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a *ngIf on a tag and the condition is false, the element is literally deleted from the DOM. So that means the `ElementRef` becomes undefined whenever your condition is false.

so the call to

```
this.searchElementRef.nativeElement
```

fatally return

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

In your case, the block view inside your ngIf is quite small so you can consider using css to hide the view. For example:

```
 <div class="flexContainer" [ngStyle]="{'display': showTextInput ? 'block' : 'none'}">
```

This way the element won't be deleted but instead just hidden and the element reference will still be valid.

But keep in mind that hiding an element using a css property implies that the view will be rendered even if the element is hidden. Which shouldn't be a problem here.

If you tried to call `initAutoComplete()` just after you set `showTextInput` to `true`, (in the same function for ex.) the view won't be updated yet and the div element won't be created. You can force update the view using the `changeDetectorRef` [see doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)
but it is not necessarily the best way as you have to wait for the view to re-render.

Comment: Thanks using the css worked fine and was a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid getting undefined @Trirandom is right, but if you want to still remove the view, there are some nice features in angular that can do that for you.

1. Create a component with the `<input>` or view that you want to hide/show.
2. Inject a ComponentFactoryResolver to create a factory for the component.
3. Use an `<ng-container>` as a ViewContainerRef.
4. Inject the ElementRef in the input component.
5. Insert and detach as you need.

Let's create the InputComponent and inject the ElementRef so you can access to the nativeElement and the innerHTML to get the input.

```
@Component({
  selector: "input-component",
  template: `
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" />
  `
})
export class InputComponent {
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

We will create a BehaviorSubject in the main component to handle the flag show/hide. Initialize it with false or true as you need.

```
showTextInput$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

The next thing is to resolve the component with the factoryComponent and then create the component. We will subscribe to the showTextInput$ so we can add/remove the view.

```
 @ViewChild("container", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public container: ViewContainerRef;

  private inputFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;
  private inputComponent: ComponentRef<InputComponent>;

 constructor(private componentFactory: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputFactory = this.componentFactory.resolveComponentFactory(
      InputComponent
    );
    this.inputComponent = this.container.createComponent(this.inputFactory);
    this.showTextInput$.subscribe(flag => {
      this.hideOrShow(flag);
    });
  }

 hideOrShow(showInput: boolean) {
    switch (showInput) {
      case true:
        this.container.insert(this.inputComponent.hostView);
        this.initAutoComplete();
        break;
      case false:
        this.container.detach();
        break;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, when the flag is true, we insert the hostView of our InputComponent, otherwise we remove it, detach does not destroy the component, just removes the view. The component is already created in `this.inputComponent` so the elementRef.nativeElement will be defined, independently of inserting/detaching the view.

In the html you could use some good practice like the `ng-template`, so you can can alternate the buttons. We create an `<ng-container>` with a `ngTemplateOutlet` and then subscribe to the showTextInput$ with the async pipe.

```html
<div id="pac-container">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <ng-container #container></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="(showTextInput$ | async) ? showButton : hideButton"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #showButton>
  <button (click)="showTextInput$.next(false)">
      <img 
      src="arrow.png" 
      alt="Hide Input">
    </button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #hideButton>
  <button (click)="showTextInput$.next(true)">
      <img 
      src="arrow.png" 
      alt="Show Input">
    </button>
</ng-template>
```

[Full example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hid-show-input?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for the sample, i was not able to use it as it created an error that the new InputCompoent was not registered. This might be due to fact that my map component is called from another Page which doesn't know anything abut the new control.

Comment: In versions prior to angular 9 you must declare the InputComponent in the `entryComponents` of the NgModule.